# How to use fail2ban with Meteor on Nginx

Tags: meteor, fail2ban

I'm setting up a Digital Ocean droplet running Ubuntu 18.04 to host my Meteor 1.8 app via Phusion Passenger / Nginx. I will configure it to use SSL with Lets Encrypt.

[fail2ban](http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) is a recommended tool to protect against brute force attacks, but I can't work out how to use it with Meteor, or even if it's appropriate. I've read [several](https://www.linode.com/docs/security/using-fail2ban-to-secure-your-server-a-tutorial/) [tutorials](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-protect-an-nginx-server-with-fail2ban-on-ubuntu-14-04) but there is something basic I don't understand.

I have used server location blocks in my Nginx config file to block access to all urls by default and only allow the necessary ones:

```
# deny all paths by default
location / { deny all; }

# allow sockjs
location /sockjs { }

# allow required paths
location = / { }
location /my-documents { }
location /login { }
location /register { }
...

# serve js and css
location ~* "^/[a-z0-9]{40}\.(css|js)$" {
  root /var/www/myapp/bundle/programs/web.browser;
  access_log off;
  expires max;
}

# serve public folder
location ~ \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|mp3|ico|pdf|svg) {
  root /var/www/myapp/bundle/pubilc;
  access_log off;
  expires max;
}

# deny unwanted requests
location ~ (\.php|.aspx|.asp|myadmin) {
  return 404;
}
```

My basic question is: would fail2ban detect failed attempts to login to my Meteor app, and if so, how? If not, then what's the purpose of it? Is it looking for failed attempts to login to the server itself? I have disabled password access on the droplet - you can only connect to the server via ssh.

And how does this relate to Nginx [password protection](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-password-authentication-with-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04) of sections of the site? Again, what's this for and do I need it? How would it work with a Meteor app?

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My conclusion is that yes, fail2ban is worth using with Meteor. As far as I can tell, Nginx password protection isn't relevant, but there's other good stuff you can do.

Firstly, I think it's worth using fail2ban on any server to block brute force attacks. My test server has been online only a couple of days with no links pointing to it and already I'm seeing probes to paths like wp-admin and robots.txt in the Nginx logs. These probes can't achieve anything because the files don't exist, but I think it's safer to ban repeated calls.

I worked from [this tutorial](https://guides.wp-bullet.com/configure-fail2ban-to-ban-nginx-403-forbidden-requests/) to set up a jail for forbidden urls, modifying the jail definition to point to my actual Nginx log file.

Then, I've modified my app to record failed login attempts and written a custom jail and filter to block these. It may be that nobody will bother to write a script to attack a Meteor site specifically, and my Meteor app has throttling on the logins, but again I feel it's better to be more careful than less.

Here's how I've modified my app:

server/main.js

```
const buildServerLogText = ((text) => {
    const connection = Meteor.call('auth.getClientConnection');

    return `${moment(new Date()).format('YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm:ss')} ${text}, client: ${connection.clientAddress}, host: "${connection.httpHeaders.host}"`;
});
// log failed login attempts so fail2ban can find them in the Nginx logs
Accounts.onLoginFailure(() => {
    const text = buildServerLogText('[error]: Meteor login failure');
    console.log(text);
});
```

This writes failed login attempts to the server in this form:

```
2020/03/10 15:40:20 [error]: Meteor login failure, client: 86.180.254.102, host: "209.97.135.5"
```

The date format is important, fail2ban is fussy about this.

I also had to set `passenger_disable_log_prefix on;` in my Phusion Passenger config file to stop a prefix being added to the log entry. As I'm deploying my app with Phusion Passenger, the Nginx config is in the Passenger config file.

Then my fail2ban filter is like this:

/etc/fail2ban/filter.d/nginx-login-failure.conf

```
[Definition]
failregex = ^ \[error\]:.*Meteor login failure.*, client: <HOST>, .*$

ignoreregex =
```

Answer (score 1):

Any modern single page application using React/Vue/Blaze as its rendering engine simply doesn't send url requests to the server for each page in the UI.

Meteor loads all its assets at the initial page load, and the rest is done over sockets using DDP. It might load static assets as separate requests.

Any server API calls implemented as Meteor methods also won't show up in server logs.

So fail2ban will detect some brute force attacks, and could therefore be useful in blocking those attacks and preventing them from swamping the server, but it won't detect failed login attempts.

You could adapt the application to detect failed logins, and call the fail2ban API to log them (if that is possible). Otherwise I'm not sure whether it is totally appropriate for protecting a meteor server.

Comment: Thanks, I think I've worked out the value of fail2ban and how to adapt Meteor to use them together. I'll post my full answer below.